# AJAX correctly handle special symbol 'enter key' | It is rendered as an empty string but not handled as empty

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, response

I use laravel/php.

I use AJAX to retrieve some data form a database.

I noticed the following issue:

If a user presses the enter key and submits the form, the database saves these presses and they look like this in the response:

```
description: "↵↵"
```

The problem is that for me it looks like an empty string in my input field:

[image]

I actually filter all empty strings like this when I get the object:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users')
->where('description', '!=', '')->where('descriptionCheck', 'No')->first();
```

I return is like this:

```
return ['success' => true, 'result' => $result];
```

Whats the correct way to handle this? It seems that other special symbols usually work.

Comment: Try by replacing `->where('description', '!=', '')` with `->whereNotNull('description')`.

Comment: is it necessary for you to save special symbols in your description field?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada Tried this already, sadly no effect, it doesnt filter at all then and even shows fields, which are actually empty.

Comment: @RomanBobrik Yeah that is the best solution, but in my situation I cant implement it, I have to work with this given dataset, which is really huge.

Comment: i find it pretty strange but anyway. you want to prevent output empty-looking strings, right?

Comment: @RomanBobrik Yes, I want to filter them, I discovered the executeRaw and TRIM(), but I am worried that it will affect performance in a negative way.